# Why does the following differential formula hold?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I am currently studying Stochastic Calculus for Continuous Time Finance models. I have stumbled upon the equation
$$
d ln(S_t) = \frac{dS_t}{S_t} - \frac{1}{2S_t^2}(d(S(t))^2 
$$
Why does that hold? I really do not get it. I thought that
$$
dln(S_t) = \frac{1}{S_t}
$$

I am not sure if this is relevant, but I have
$$
dS_t = r_t S_t dt + \sigma_t S_t d\tilde{W}_t
$$

Comment: [Ito's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma). Your last formula is not relevant.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying Kurt G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Kurt G. for clarifying. It is now clear to me. For some reason, I did not even think of that. But, we use Ito's Lemma with $f = ln(S_t)$, so that
$$
f_t = 0 \\
f_{x} = \frac{1}{S_t} dS_t \\
f_{xx} = -\frac{1}{S_t^2} (d(S(t))^2
$$
Adding these terms we get
$$
dln(S_t) = \frac{dS_t}{S_t} - \frac{1}{S_t^2} (d(S_t))^2
$$
In this particular situation, with $=+\tilde{W}_t$, we then get
$$
d lnS_t= r_t dt + \sigma_t d\tilde{W}_t - \frac{1}{2S_t^2}(d(S(t))^2
$$
$$
d lnS_t = r_tdt + \sigma_t d\tilde{W}_t - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2dt
$$
where $(d(S_t))^2$ is computed using $dtdt = dtW_t = 0$ and $dW_tdW_t = dt$